# How to remove commits and replace them with the new commits

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I wanted to go back and start from a certain commit so I did a hard reset and then I committed those changes now my log looks like in the picture. So what I want to do is completely replace those 2 old commits with the new 2 commits like those old 2 commits never happened. Is there a way to do this?

[image: How my log looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local looks good. You have to rewrite your remote repo.

```
git push origin --force
```

Comment: You will also need to check the branch rules on Github to see if `master` is protected and temporarily disable this if necessary. (By "you" I mean the OP or future visitors.)

Comment: I'd highly recommend `--force-with-lease` here to make sure you know exactly what you're blowing away, in case new commits have appeared on `origin/master` that you don't know about yet.